Correlation between number of tries scored in a rugby match
I have a set of Data from the 2024 Rugby Season.
There are say 250 trials.
Column A shows how many tries the home team scored ins each game (X)
Column B shows how many tries the away team scored ins each game (Y)
The correlation coefficient between X and Y is -50%
However, when I rearrange the data so :
that X1 is the maximum of each trail of X & Y
and  Y1 is the minimum of each trial of X & Y
the correlation co-efficient of X1 and Y1 reduces to -8%
Can someone help explain what is going on here and what is the true correlation between the number of tries opposing teams score in rugby.
The data looks like this:



N
X
Y
X1
Y1




1
7
2
7
2


2
4
3
4
3


3
2
4
4
2


4
3
4
4
3


.

--
--
--


N=250
4
2
4
2


Corel

-50%

-8%



thanks

Your second paragraph may have a typing error.  Presumably $Y$ is the number of tries scored by the away team.
